# Instant signal frequency change on amplifier

Tags: amplifier, rf, oscillation

I was wondering what happens to an amplifier when the frequency is suddenly changed from (in my case) 2401 MHz to 2479 MHz. Would the amplifier somehow oscillate at the beginning or would it be steady?

The amplifier ranges from 2300 MHz to 2500 MHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip away the narrow-band matching networks used before and after an RF amplifier, those networks needed for efficiency etc, and you'll find a quite
broadband circuit/device. The device's junction parasitics may require inductors, to convert the parasitics into a narrow-band helpful network, but the transistor will be broadband, performing as a Low Pass Filter. Given the LPF behavior, perhaps with F3dB at Fcarrier, an abrupt but modest change in Fcarrier may be undetectable in output amplitude changes.

However, bring back the matching networks, with Q of 5 or 10, and possible with complex peaking performed by microstrip or stripline resonators at 2,000MHz, and the STORED ENERGY at F1 must decay and the NEW STORED ENERGY at F2 must build up. A Q=5 filter decays at 6dB per cycle. This agrees with Andy.

Again, the device is fast, the matching networks store the energy and thus constrain the speed of response.

By the way, harmonics do not exist, being merely an artifact of our math.

Comment: Harmonics do exist because you can tune into the harmonics of a square wave for instance with a regular band pass filter.

Answer (score 1):

Any instant change to an input signal will produce a series of harmonics that will far exceed the capabilities of **any** amplifier. This means that an instantaneous change might produce an output of a decaying, ringing oscillation or a sluggish waveform that didn't follow the input exactly.

If you have a specific circuit example then this can be run through a simulator to demonstrate what happens.

> The amplifier ranges from 2300 MHz to 2500 MHz

The devil is in the detail.